# Adding HSTS Response Header using ExchangeFilterFunction in springboot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webclient, response-headers

I am trying to add hsts header using ExhangeFilterFunction using spring webclient. Following below are the reference code.

```
 @Bean
public WebClient client(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
    try {
        return WebClient 
                .builder() 
                .filter(returnResponseHeader()) // Set the response specific headers
                .defaultHeader(ACCEPT, APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE) // Is not changed between requests
                .defaultHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE) // Is not changed between requests
                .build();
    }catch(HttpMessageNotReadableException e) {
        return null;
    }
    
} 

@Bean
public ExchangeFilterFunction returnResponseHeader() {
    return ExchangeFilterFunction.ofResponseProcessor(response -> {
         var newResponse = ClientResponse.from(response); 
        return Mono.just(newResponse            
                .header()
                .httpStrictTransportSecurity()
                .includeSubDomains(true)
                .maxAgeInSeconds(31536000)
                .build());
    });
}
```

But in this case getting compile time error, not sure how to add using ExchangeFilterFunction.